# Extension errors when retrieving cookie of site and posting to it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cookies, google-chrome-extension

In my code, I wish to post to two php files using a cookie from the website it is posting to (meepcity.com). However, upon loading the chrome extension, I receive the following two errors:

`Error in response to cookies.get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at token`

As well as

`Unchecked runtime.lastError while running cookies.get: No host permissions for cookies at url: "http://www.meepcity/". at token`

I do not see anything wrong with my code, though I assume the problem has to do with the retrieval of the cookies. I have included my code as well as my manifest below. Thanks!

```
function token(domain, name, callback) {
    chrome.cookies.get({"url": domain, "name": name}, function(cookie) {
        if(callback) {
            callback(cookie.value);
        }
    });
}
token("http://www.meepcity", "PHPSESSID", function(secureToken) {
    function buy(id, security) {
        $.ajax({url:"http://api.meepcity.com/prepareAssetPurchase.php",type:"POST",data:{sess:security,aId:id,sId:0}})
        $.ajax({url:"https://api.meepcity.com/finishAssetPurchase.php",type:"POST",data:{sess:security}}).done(function() { console.info("Successfully purchased!"); });
}
    buy(44,secureToken);
});
```

Manifest

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "jquery.js", "background.js" ]
   },
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
   "description": "Meepcity",
   "homepage_url": "http://www.meepcity.com/",
   "incognito": "split",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Meepcity",
   "permissions": [ "unlimitedStorage", "tabs", "notifications", "tabCapture", "*://*.meepcity.com/*", "https://*.meepcity.com/*", "cookies", "background" ],
   "short_name": "Meepcity",
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.0.1",
   "web_accessible_resources": [ "*://*.meepcity.com/*", "https://*.meepcity.com/*" ]
}
```

Thanks, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but I think you should do this:

1. Change "http://www.meepcity" to "https://www.meepcity.com"
2. Change {"url": domain, "name": name} to {"url": domain, "name": name, secure: true}

Hope it works